# Maven reactor test завершается успешно при упавших тестах

Tags: java, maven, junit, cucumber

мульти-модульный проект, тесты запскаются командой

```
mvn -am -pl bdd_test clean test -DENV=sandbox "-Dcucumber.options=--plugin pretty --tags @my_tag"
```

После этого выполняется тест,

```
                                                # SalesTest.check*******(String,int)

Failed scenarios:
src/test/resources/features/***********.feature:14 # 01 - Scenario 1

1 Scenarios (1 failed)
40 Steps (1 failed, 38 skipped, 1 passed)
0m0,398s

java.lang.AssertionError: a
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at ;;;;;;;;;;;;.******.fail(*****.java:596)
    at ✽.fail(src/test/resources/features/***********.feature:10)

[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 6.748 s - in TestSuite
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] ********* 1.0.0 ................................ SUCCESS [  0.003 s]
[INFO] ********* ................................... SUCCESS [  0.831 s]
[INFO] ********* 1.66.0 ........................... SUCCESS [  0.904 s]
[INFO] ********* ..................................... SUCCESS [  4.087 s]
[INFO] bdd_test 1.0.0 ..................................... SUCCESS [  8.927 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.910 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-04-22T15:48:54+03:00
```

Но мне необходимо, чтобы build завершился фейлом, чтобы CI система откатила сборку.

bdd_test.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>autotests_all</artifactId>
        <groupId>ru.abs</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>bdd_test</artifactId>
    <!--<packaging>jar</packaging>-->

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ru.abs</groupId>
                <artifactId>page-factory-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.66.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ru.sbtqa.tag</groupId>
                <artifactId>qa-utils</artifactId>
                <version>${tag.version.qautils}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ru.sbtqa.tag.datajack.providers</groupId>
                <artifactId>json-provider</artifactId>
                <version>${tag.version.datajack}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>autotest</groupId>
                <artifactId>autotest</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                <version>20180813</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
                <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipAfterFailureCount>1</skipAfterFailureCount>
                    <junitArtifactName>junit:junit</junitArtifactName>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                        -Dcucumber.options="--plugin io.qameta.allure.cucumber2jvm.AllureCucumber2Jvm --plugin pretty"
                     </argLine>
                 </configuration>
                 <dependencies>
                     <dependency>
                         <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                         <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                         <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                     </dependency>
                 </dependencies>
             </plugin>
             <plugin>
                 <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                 <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                 <version>2.8</version>
                 <configuration>
                     <resultsDirectory>${project.basedir}/allure-results</resultsDirectory>
                     <reportDirectory>${project.basedir}/allure-report</reportDirectory>
                 </configuration>
             </plugin>
         </plugins>
     </build>

 </project>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>******</groupId>
    <artifactId>autotests_all</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>


    <modules>
        <module>bdd_test</module>
        <module>******</module>
        <module>******</module>
        <module>******</module>
        <module>******</module>
        <module>******</module>
        <module>******</module>
        <module>******</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <selenium.version>3.141.59</selenium.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <cucumber.version>2.4.0</cucumber.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.9.2</aspectj.version>
        <aspectj.plugin.version>1.11</aspectj.plugin.version>
        <spring.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <activemq.version>5.13.0</activemq.version>
        <surefire.version>2.22.1</surefire.version>
        <tag.version.qautils>1.5.0</tag.version.qautils>
        <tag.version.videorecorder>1.0.7</tag.version.videorecorder>
        <tag.version.webdrivermanager>2.2.2</tag.version.webdrivermanager>
        <tag.version.datajack>4.0.4</tag.version.datajack>
        <allure.version>2.10.0</allure.version>
    </properties>


    <reporting>
        <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: как понять упавшие тесты, если у вас в логах везде `SUCCESS`?

Comment: @FarkhodDaniyarov исправил лог вывода, тест падает

Comment: извините, но разве не вот это строчка сообщает об тестах: `[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 6.748 s` а в ней, все вроде по `0`

Comment: Тогда я окончательно не понимаю что происходит. Я запустит тесты и они прошли. Почему этот счетчик на нуле? Я что-то делаю не так. Можете помочь что именно?

Comment: И откуда взялось Time elapsed и  - in TestSuite?

Comment: Я нашел похожую https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48399561/cucumber-test-results-always-return-0-if-run-from-maven но у меня используется JUnit

Comment: я не совсем уверен, но разве у вас в зависемостях не сидит `testng`?

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил этого. теперь Тест падает как положено, это конфликт testng и junit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это конфликт junit и testng.
Нужно избавиться от всех зависимостей testng, не только в основном pom.xml но и в связанных классах, где есть testng.assert